# Zend: Generating partial in command line

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have set of class that send mails to my coworkers, while specific event happens. I had no problem with this so far, until today. I have to run some code from `CLI` (target - `cron`) to send daily reports. As you might suspect - no controller nor view is involved.

My code:

```
/**
 * Returns mail content
 * 
 * @param Crm_Mail_Abstract_AlertMail $object
 * @return string
 * @throws Exception
 */
private function generateContent(Crm_Mail_Abstract_AlertMail $object)
{

    $subContent = $object->getInnerContent();

    if (!$subContent) {
        throw new Exception('Cannot load subcontent');
    }

    $view = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
    $content = $view->partial($this->mainLayout, array('content' => $subContent));

    return $content;
}
```

And the error I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getView() on a non-object 
in /home/..../library/Crm/Mail/AlertMail.php on line 195
```

So... how to render partials while in terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to This : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.layout.quickstart.html

```
// Returns null if startMvc() has not first been called
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
```

So, if you didn't added this :

```
// In your bootstrap:
Zend_Layout::startMvc();
```

You will not access this -

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()
```

So try do this something like that:

```
Zend_Layout::startMvc();
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView();
```